# Android valgrind build fails on Mavericks

Tags: c, android-ndk

I'm trying to build valgrind for android-arm on my OS X (Mavericks).  ./configure runs successfully but make gives me following error (I have removed some of the line from error log to keep it short):

```
 valgrind-3.10.1 gausharm$ make
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
    Making all in include
    make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    Making all in VEX
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
    make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
    Making all in coregrind
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
    mkdir -p ../.in_place; \
        for f in vgpreload_core-arm-linux.so  ; do \
          rm -f ../.in_place/$f; \
          ln -f -s ../coregrind/$f ../.in_place; \
        done
    for f in ; do \
          if [ ! -e $f.dSYM  -o  $f -nt $f.dSYM ] ; then \
              echo "dsymutil $f"; \
              dsymutil $f; \
          fi; \
        done
    mkdir -p ../.in_place; \
        for f in ; do \
          rm -f ../.in_place/$f.dSYM; \
          ln -f -s ../coregrind/$f.dSYM ../.in_place; \
        done
    mkdir -p ../.in_place; \
        for f in m_gdbserver/32bit-core-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-core-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-core.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-linux-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-linux-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-linux.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-sse-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-sse-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/32bit-sse.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-avx-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-avx-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-avx.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-core-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-core-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-core.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-linux-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-linux-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-linux.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-sse-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-sse-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/64bit-sse.xml m_gdbserver/amd64-avx-coresse-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/amd64-avx-coresse.xml m_gdbserver/amd64-avx-linux-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/amd64-avx-linux.xml m_gdbserver/amd64-coresse-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/amd64-linux-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/arm-core-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/arm-core-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/arm-core.xml m_gdbserver/arm-vfpv3-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/arm-vfpv3-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/arm-vfpv3.xml m_gdbserver/arm-with-vfpv3-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/arm-with-vfpv3.xml m_gdbserver/i386-coresse-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/i386-linux-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/power64-core-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/power64-core-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/power64-core.xml m_gdbserver/power64-linux-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/power64-linux-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/power64-linux.xml m_gdbserver/power-altivec-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/power-altivec-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/power-altivec.xml m_gdbserver/power-core-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/power-core-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/power-core.xml m_gdbserver/power-fpu-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/power-fpu-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/power-fpu.xml m_gdbserver/power-linux-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/power-linux-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/power-linux.xml m_gdbserver/powerpc-altivec32l-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/powerpc-altivec32l.xml m_gdbserver/powerpc-altivec64l-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/powerpc-altivec64l.xml m_gdbserver/s390-acr-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/s390-acr-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/s390-acr.xml m_gdbserver/s390-fpr-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/s390-fpr-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/s390-fpr.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-core64-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-core64-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-core64.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-generic-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-generic.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-linux64-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-linux64-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/s390x-linux64.xml m_gdbserver/mips-cp0-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/mips-cp0-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/mips-cp0.xml m_gdbserver/mips-cpu-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/mips-cpu-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/mips-cpu.xml m_gdbserver/mips-linux.xml m_gdbserver/mips-linux-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/mips-fpu-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/mips-fpu-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/mips-fpu.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-cp0-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-cp0-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-cp0.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-cpu-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-cpu-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-cpu.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-linux.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-linux-valgrind.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-fpu-valgrind-s1.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-fpu-valgrind-s2.xml m_gdbserver/mips64-fpu.xml; do \
          rm -f ../.in_place/$f; \
          ln -f -s ../coregrind/$f ../.in_place; \
        done
    Making all in .
    mkdir -p ./.in_place
    rm -f ./.in_place/default.supp
    ln -s ../default.supp ./.in_place
    Making all in memcheck
    Making all in .
    ../coregrind/link_tool_exe_linux 0x38000000 /Users/gausharm/Softwares/android-ndk-r10b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -Wno-long-long --sysroot=/Users/gausharm/Softwares/android-ndk-r10b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -fno-stack-protector   -o memcheck-arm-linux -O2 -g -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-format-zero-length -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin -marm -mcpu=cortex-a8 -O2 -static -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles -u _start  -Wl,-z,noexecstack memcheck_arm_linux-mc_leakcheck.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_malloc_wrappers.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_main.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_translate.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_machine.o memcheck_arm_linux-mc_errors.o ../coregrind/libcoregrind-arm-linux.a ../VEX/libvex-arm-linux.a -lgcc 
    /Users/gausharm/Softwares/android-ndk-r10b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ../coregrind/libcoregrind-arm-linux.a: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
    /Users/gausharm/Softwares/android-ndk-r10b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ../VEX/libvex-arm-linux.a: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
    mc_leakcheck.c:1878: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_umsg'

.'vgPlain_null_ExeContext'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:305: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_record_ExeContext'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:319: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_record_ExeContext'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:438: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_memset'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:112: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_free_queue_volume'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:112: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_free_queue_length'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:193: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_allocEltPA'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:165: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_cli_free'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:223: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_freeEltPA'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:215: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_tool_panic'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:139: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_free_queue_volume'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:139: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_free_queue_length'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:367: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_add_node'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:350: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_cli_malloc'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:359: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_memset'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:367: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_add_node'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:372: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_ECU_from_ExeContext'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:355: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_memset'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:367: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_add_node'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:388: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_alignment'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:398: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_alignment'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:408: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_alignment'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:429: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_alignment'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:481: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_remove'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:527: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_remove'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:545: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_cli_malloc'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:574: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_memcpy'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:607: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_memset'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:581: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_memcpy'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:586: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_ECU_from_ExeContext'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:628: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_lookup'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:642: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_lookup'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:657: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_record_ExeContext'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:658: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_ECU_from_ExeContext'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:689: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_lookup'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:698: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_construct'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:686: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_running_tid'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:686: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_and_pp_StackTrace'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:707: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_tool_panic'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:691: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_verbosity'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:724: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_remove'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:741: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_destruct'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:721: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_running_tid'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:721: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_and_pp_StackTrace'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:727: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_running_tid'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:839: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_and_pp_StackTrace'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:865: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_running_tid'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:875: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_and_pp_StackTrace'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:917: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_HT_to_array'
    mc_malloc_wrappers.c:1108: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_xml'
    mc_main.c:6769: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_free_queue_length'
    mc_main.c:6769: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_free_queue_volume'
    mc_main.c:921: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_Create_With_Pool'
    mc_main.c:1015: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_Lookup'
    mc_main.c:1031: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_AllocNode'
    mc_main.c:1039: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_Insert'
    mc_main.c:943: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_ResetIter'
    mc_main.c:944: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_Next'
    mc_main.c:952: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_AllocNode'
    mc_main.c:955: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_Insert'
    mc_main.c:966: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_Destroy'
    mc_main.c:971: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_percentify'
    mc_main.c:5399: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_printf'
    mc_main.c:5363: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_printf'
    mc_main.c:6819: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_sizeRangeMap'
    mc_main.c:6823: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_indexRangeMap'
    mc_main.c:6791: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_xml'
    mc_main.c:6791: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_stats'
    mc_main.c:6579: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_4'
    mc_main.c:6580: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_8'
    mc_main.c:6581: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_12'
    mc_main.c:6582: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_16'
    mc_main.c:6583: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_32'
    mc_main.c:6584: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_112'
    mc_main.c:6585: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_128'
    mc_main.c:6586: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_144'
    mc_main.c:6587: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_160'
    mc_main.c:6589: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack'
    mc_main.c:6590: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_signal'
    mc_main.c:6646: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_brk'
    mc_main.c:6660: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_newPA'
    mc_main.c:6668: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_pre_reg_read'
    mc_main.c:2360: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_am_shadow_alloc'
    mc_main.c:2414: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_OSetGen_Create'
    mc_main.c:6644: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_brk'
    mc_main.c:6564: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_4_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6565: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_8_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6566: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_12_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6567: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_16_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6568: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_32_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6569: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_112_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6570: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_128_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6571: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_144_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6572: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_160_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6574: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_w_ECU'
    mc_main.c:6575: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_track_new_mem_stack_signal'
    mc_main.c:2362: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_out_of_memory_NORETURN'
    mc_main.c:6655: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_clo_xml'
    mc_main.c:301: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_am_shadow_alloc'
    mc_main.c:305: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_memcpy'

    mc_errors.c:1000: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_addr_is_in_block'
    mc_errors.c:1066: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_initThreadInfo'
    mc_errors.c:1006: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_addr_is_in_block'
    mc_errors.c:1229: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_initThreadInfo'
    mc_errors.c:1072: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_describe_addr'
    mc_errors.c:313: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_snprintf'
    mc_errors.c:311: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_snprintf'
    mc_errors.c:410: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_extra'
    mc_errors.c:412: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_kind'
    mc_errors.c:446: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_where'
    mc_errors.c:459: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_where'
    mc_errors.c:421: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_string'
    mc_errors.c:479: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_string'
    mc_errors.c:501: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_string'
    mc_errors.c:546: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_where'
    mc_errors.c:547: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_address'
    mc_errors.c:547: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_pp_addrinfo_mc'
    mc_errors.c:667: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_where'
    mc_errors.c:668: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_address'
    mc_errors.c:668: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_pp_addrinfo_mc'
    mc_errors.c:643: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_string'
    mc_errors.c:703: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_kind'
    mc_errors.c:663: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_address'
    mc_errors.c:668: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_pp_addrinfo_mc'
    mc_errors.c:603: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_address'
    mc_errors.c:739: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_is_watched'
    mc_errors.c:742: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_SP'
    mc_errors.c:753: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_maybe_record_error'
    mc_errors.c:765: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_maybe_record_error'
    mc_errors.c:776: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_maybe_record_error'
    mc_errors.c:784: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_maybe_record_error'
    mc_errors.c:843: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_initThreadInfo'
    mc_errors.c:877: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_unique_error'
    mc_errors.c:930: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_extra'
    mc_errors.c:931: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_extra'
    mc_errors.c:934: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_kind'
    mc_errors.c:934: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_kind'
    mc_errors.c:1081: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_pp_addrinfo_mc'
    mc_errors.c:1099: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_error_extra'
    mc_errors.c:1296: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_set_supp_kind'
    mc_errors.c:1325: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_kind'
    mc_errors.c:1326: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_line'
    mc_errors.c:1329: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_kind'
    mc_errors.c:1352: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_kind'
    mc_errors.c:1328: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_strdup'
    mc_errors.c:1328: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_set_supp_string'
    mc_errors.c:1337: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_set_supp_extra'
    mc_errors.c:1338: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_line'
    mc_errors.c:1342: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_isspace'
    mc_errors.c:1356: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_line'
    mc_errors.c:1360: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_strdup'
    mc_errors.c:1363: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_strchr'
    mc_errors.c:1367: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_strchr'
    mc_errors.c:1371: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_set_supp_extra'
    mc_errors.c:1382: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_kind'
    mc_errors.c:1393: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_string'
    mc_errors.c:1393: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_string'
    mc_errors.c:1442: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_extra'
    mc_errors.c:1426: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_extra'
    mc_errors.c:1521: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_snprintf'
    mc_errors.c:1510: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_snprintf'
    mc_errors.c:1533: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_extra'
    mc_errors.c:1551: error: undefined reference to 'vgPlain_get_supp_extra'
    /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.S:1335: error: undefined reference to 'raise'
    /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:289: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
    /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:346: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
    /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:376: error: undefined reference to 'memcpy'
    /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc:505: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
    /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/config/arm/pr-support.c:378: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
    /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/libgcc/config/arm/pr-support.c:384: error: undefined reference to 'abort'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[3]: *** [memcheck-arm-linux] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am using following script to configure:

```
export NDK_HOME=$HOME/Softwares/android-ndk-r10b

export HWKIND=generic

export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi
#export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/mipsel-linux-android
#export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android

export AR=$TOOLCHAIN-ar
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN-ld
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN-gcc
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN-g++
#export CPP=$TOOLCHAIN-cpp

CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$NDK_HOME/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -DANDROID_HARDWARE_$HWKIND" \
    CFLAGS="--sysroot=$NDK_HOME/platforms/android-14/arch-arm" \
    ./configure  CPP="$CPP" CC="$CC" CXX="$CXX" LD="$LD" AR="$AR" --prefix=/data/local/Inst \
    --host=armv7-unknown-linux --target=armv7-unknown-linux \
    --with-tmpdir=/sdcard
```

Above script gives me following output:

```
     Maximum build arch: arm
     Primary build arch: arm
   Secondary build arch: 
               Build OS: linux
   Primary build target: ARM_LINUX
 Secondary build target: 
       Platform variant: android
  Primary -DVGPV string: -DVGPV_arm_linux_android=1
     Default supp files: exp-sgcheck.supp xfree-3.supp xfree-4.supp bionic.supp
```